# How to get a list of Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set Instances using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, instance, azure-vm-scale-set

I am trying to get a list of all Virtual Machine Instances within all Scale Sets of a subscription using powershell.

I have been able to list out all the Scalesets by using the code below, but I would like to show all the Virtual Machine instances within each one.

$azureSubs = Get-AzSubscription -TenantID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

$azureSubs | ForEach-Object {Select-AzSubscription $_ | Out-Null; Get-AzVMss -WarningAction SilentlyContinue} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Azure\VirtualMachinesScaleSet.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Can anyone suggest anything to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Get-AzVmssVM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmssvm?view=azps-3.0.0) command, try the script below in each subscription.

```
$vmss = Get-AzVmss
$instances = foreach($item in $vmss){
    Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $item.Name
}
$instances | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\ins.csv"
```

[image]

**Update**:

For multiple subscriptions in a tenant,try the script below.

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "<tenant-id>"
$instances = @()
foreach($sub in $subs){
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id
    $vmss = Get-AzVmss
    foreach($item in $vmss){
        $vms = Get-AzVmssVM -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $item.Name
        $instances += $vms
    }
}
$instances | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ins.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for this Joy...this certainly gets the instances for one subscription.

Comment: Do you know what changes to the code would need to be made in order to get the instances for multiple subscriptions in a tenant, without having to run the above script against each one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Get-AzureRmVM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/get-azurermvm?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to get the hostname and instance id:

```
PS > Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "vmss" -VMScaleSetName "vmss"
```

Comment: Not sure, but your answer is correct and I've up-voted you to remove the negative.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but perhaps because the AzureRm libraries are deprecated.

Comment: @MikeOryszak Yup, thanks :) now it should make sense

Comment: It's downvoted because it's the wrong api. I think they meant Get-AzureRmVmssVM

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get-AzVmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmss?view=azps-3.0.0) (leverages the Az library) to get scale set info.

```
PS Get-AzVmss
```